# Maven: eliminate all but latest version of library in local repo

Tags: java, maven

There's a library that I am using in my project and I have gone through many versions of it during development, so my local Maven repository contains many of the older versions of this library.

I suspect conflicts might be causing some strange issues I have been having, so I want to eliminate all but the latest version of this library from my local maven repository.

How do I do this?

If it makes any difference, I am currently using a SNAPSHOT version of this library (as recommended by its developers).

PS: deleting the entire repository is not a very practical option, as the repo is currently over 1.2G and I have a slow, capped connection.

Comment: Why dont u delete the whole repository ? :), maven should then download the needed dependencies

Comment: @EnoqueDuarte See above (just added it): deleting entire repo isn't very practical for me :-).

Comment: what about deleting manually then ? xd, or try this :http://samulisiivonen.blogspot.pt/2012/01/cleanin-up-maven-dependencies.html

Comment: @EnoqueDuarte thanks for the link, I might have to resort to this :-), though thankfully mine is a young project with only a few dependencies (though I've gone through multiple versions of most).

Comment: another option, is to create an artifactory locally, then copy your repo to artifactory, delete it, and recompile pointing the maven to artifactory, it would "download" only whats needed, and since its on ur machine, it would be fast

Comment: Start using a repository manager will help you such situations.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the dependency coordinates you can delete them manually from the local directory.  For example if this was your dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

On Linux you could run:

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/jersey-bom/
```

On Windows you can use explorer to delete it or run:

```
rd /S /Q C:\Users\%username%\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\jersey-bom\
```

Answer (score 1):

[purge-local-repository plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html) for maven could help in this situation.

Try to execute maven with following command :

```
mvn clean dependency:purge-local-repository -DreResolve=false -Dverbose=true -DactTransitively=false
```