# How to delete a specific library from local maven repo

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project. I would like to delete a specific library from my local maven repository so that when I use `mvn clean install` my project, it fetches the library from my remote central repository.

I've tried searching how to do it but they all consist of deleting the entire repository folder in the `.m2` directory and that's not ideal for me.

Comment: You don't need to delete the library if you want to download it every time. You can  pass `-U` to force maven to download the dependencies You can do `mvn clean install -U`.

Comment: You can use **mvn dependency:purge-local-repository**. But this command delete the local repository files but it always goes and fills up the local repository after things have been removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: eliminate all but latest version of library in local repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186661/maven-eliminate-all-but-latest-version-of-library-in-local-repo)

Comment: The first question is: Why do you need to do a `mvn clean install`? Isn't `mvn clean verfiy` enough?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to delete the library from the m2 directory, there is an official way to do this.

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DmanualInclude="groupId:artifactId, ..
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to delete whole repository try to find library to delete in it by `groupId` + `artifactId`. For example

```
<groupId>com.google.services</groupId>
<artifactId>proxy-service</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

library will be located in `~.m2/com/google/services/proxy-service/1.0.0/` You can delete just `proxy-service` directory or even `1.0.0` inside in case if you are using multiple versions. After that maven reload library from remote

Answer (score 0):

Local maven repository is just a directory located in `$HOME/.m2/repository/`. Locate your library there and just remove the directory where the files are stored.